# Literal 0.57 value less precision between vb.net and c++

Tags: c++, vb.net

i have an dll writed in c++ i have is function

```
int FiscalPrinter::Pay(const int iPayType,const int iPayForm,
                System::String ^sPayFormDescription, const double dAmount) {
...
}
```

now in vb.net

```
dAmount = 0.57
If (FiscalPrinter.Pay(iPayType, iPayForm, sPayFormDescription, dAmount) = 
     FiscalPrinter.ansOK) Then
```

the problem is in vb.net send 0.57 c++'s dll receive 0.56999999999999995,

reading msdn it said

> the floating-point value provides an imprecise representation of the
>   number that it represents. For example, if we compare the result of
>   multiplying .1 by 10 and adding .1 to .1 nine times, we see that
>   addition, because it has involved eight more operations, has produced
>   the less precise result.

now if i send 0.57000000000000006 c++ receive one value more accurate

> So, how should i send values how 0.57 or anyvalue and that arrived suitably??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an integer instead, perhaps by representing your currency in cents:

```
iAmount = 57
```

and your function should be

```
int FiscalPrinter::Pay(const int iPayType,const int iPayForm,
                System::String ^sPayFormDescription, const int iAmount) {
```

Integers do not have the round-off issues that floating-point values have. For more information, see the Oracle article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).